# What does the %= operator do?

Tags: c#

What does the `%=` operator do, as shown in this example:

```
if (a > b)
   a %= b;
```

What are its uses and is it commonly used?

Comment: `%=` is not an operator. It contains two seperate operators [`%`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) and [`=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx). So basicly, `a %= b;` is equavalent to `a = a % b;`

Comment: @SonerGönül Microsoft seems to call it an operator all on its own http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydwa9zh0.aspx

Comment: @MikeClark Wow.. I never noticed that before. Thanks for clarification `:)`

Comment: It certainly is an operator! It is the compound remainder operator.

Comment: Of course, [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314.aspx) also says: _The assignment operators other than the `=` operator are called the compound assignment operators. These operators perform the indicated operation on the two operands, and then assign the resulting value to the variable, property, or indexer element given by the left operand._

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx):

> The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder operators.

So in your case, the following string

```
a %= b;
```

is the same as this one:

```
a = a % b;
```

Which also applies to all operators:

`a += b` equals to `a = a + b`
`a /= b` equals to `a = a / b`
`a -= b` equals to `a = a - b`
etc.

Comment: ```a <= b``` equals to ```a = a < b```? Wow! ;)

Comment: @Gankro: That was the subject of my 2011 April Fools Day post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/01/compound-assignment-part-two.aspx -- note that part one of this article is serious, but part two is a joke.

Comment: @Eric: My life has been enriched by this link.

Answer (score 2):

It's a shortcut for

```
a = a % b;
```

which gets the *remainder* of `a` and `b` and stores the result in `a`.

Comment: It gets the *remainder*, not the *modulus*. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert thaks for the article `:)`

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as this:

```
a = a % b
```

Answer (score 0):

% is a [% operator of C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx), that

> computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second

So `5 % 2` would equal to `1` .

The `a %= b` is equal to `a = a % b`, just short way to write the same thing, as

```
i+=a => i = i + a
i*=a => i = i * a
i/=a => i = i / a
```

Answer (score 0):

`%=` is a compound operator.It is similar to `a = a % b`

% is used get the remainder

```
5 %= 2;//1
6%=2;//0
```

---

Generally `%` is used to to map many elements to less number of elements..

So,if you have 100 elements and you want to map them to say an array of 20 elements..You can use % operator

```
99%20;//19...So assign 99 to array index 19
50%20;//10...So assign 50 to array index 10
```